# Image update using GCP deployment manager

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-deployment-manager

I'm looking for a way to update the image on which my compute engine instance is built. Deployment update should spin up a new instance with the new image and original data disk attached.

Is there any way in which this objective can be fulfilled using GCP deployment manager?

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by defining the data disk separately from the instance.

Here's a [link](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/best-practices/#managing_resources) with useful information about it.

Comment: Data disk has been defined seperately only. My objective is to destroy the boot disk and recreate the instance in such a way that original data disk should be attached to new boot disk.